# Object doesn't move smooth over edges?

Tags: unity, movement, meshcollider

In the last couple of days I'm experimenting a lot with Unity 3D to get a feeling about the environment and the behavior of game development. I come from a programming perspective and try to develop as much as possible in Unity 3D.

I created a base controller which creates a 10x10 surfaces area on start. Each part is based on a prefab plane (scale: 0.1, 0.1, 0.1) with an appended box collider. On this surface area I'm moving an object with the `AddForce` method. So far everything works fine.

However, if my moving object reach the edge of a surface area part (prefab plane) it breaks and I am not able to move the object directly over the edges. Sometimes it stops completely. If I use a bigger prefab plane I'm able to move my object smooth on that part, but it also stops at the edges.

[image]

Do you have an idea, why the cube stops at the edges?

> Edit

I think this behavior occur because the cube hit a new collider surface. My currently fix calculate an overlaying `BoxCollider` over all surface elements. With this implementation there are no collider edges.

Is this an acceptable implementation?

```
public class Surface : MonoBehaviour {

    private static readonly GameObject GameObject1 = new GameObject("Surface");

    private static readonly GameObject GameObject2 = (GameObject) Resources.Load("Ground");

    private static readonly BoxCollider BoxCollider = GameObject1.AddComponent<BoxCollider> ();

    private GameObject obj;

    public void Draw() {
        this.obj = Instantiate (Surface.GameObject2, new Vector3 (this.X, this.Y, this.Z), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        this.Add ();
    }

    private void Add() {
        this.obj.transform.parent = Surface.GameObject1.transform;

        Surface.BoxCollider.size = new Vector3 (this.X, this.Y, this.Z);
    }

    public static Surface Create(int x, int z) {
        var surface = Surface.GameObject1.AddComponent<Surface>();
        surface.x = x;
        surface.y = 0;
        surface.z = z;

        return surface;
    }
}
```

The single surfaces are created with a simple loop.

```
private static readonly Surface[] Surfaces = new Surface[Width * Height];

for (var z = 0; z < Width; z++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < Height; x++) {
        Surfaces[x + z] = Surface.Create(x, z);
        Surfaces[x + z].Draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: The texture is blue with a white boarder.

Comment: Have you checked `Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics` settings? I once had a similar issue, maybe you can find something useful there.